# Coordinate systems on manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, coordinate-systems

I am fairly new to differential geometry and something I can't get my head around is, if an $n$-dimensional manifold is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, i.e. Euclidean space, then isn't it possible to cover any manifold with a collection of coordinate charts whose coordinates are just the usual Cartesian coordinates of Euclidean space? Why does one need to even consider more general, cuvilinear coordinate systems, other than that they may simplify the problem at hand?

For example, the 2-sphere $S^{2}$ can be locally described (perhaps most easily) by spherical polar coordinates  $(\theta , \phi)$ that can be mapped to local Cartesian coordinates, $x^{1}=\sin (\theta)\cos (\phi),\; x^{2}=\sin (\theta)\sin (\phi),\; x^{3}=\cos (\theta)$. Couldn't one equally just start from the definition of $S^{2}=\lbrace (x^{1},x^{2},x^{3})\in\mathbb{R}^{3}\;\vert\; (x^{1})^{2}+(x^{2})^{2}+(x^{3})^{2}=1\rbrace$ and just use Cartesian coordinates (forgoing curvilinear coordinates altogether)?

However, I have read that, in general, curved manifolds cannot be described even locally by Cartesian coordinates. I'm confused how this is the case when supposedly all manifolds are locally homeomorphic to Euclidean space?

Comment: It depends on what you ask for your coordinate systems. If you want only them to reflect the topology of the manifold, then you're right, it's always locally possible and then a collection of charts will cover your whole manifold. The thing you've read, on the other hand, deals with more that mere topology. If you want your chart to reflect geometric properties of your space (angles, lengths, areas...) then it is in general not possible, even locally. It's a thing cartographers learned a long time ago: you can represent angles nicely, areas nicely, but not both at the same time.

Comment: In what sense are the coordinates you give for $S^2$ not "curvilinear"? Your question is not a precise one but I suspect your confusion is in the distinction between (smooth) topology and geometry - curved manifolds cannot be given coordinates *so that the metric takes the form $dx^2 + dy^2 + \cdots$.* Remember that when dealing with spherical polar coordinates you have to use special formulae for distances, areas, etc, so the geometry is *not* that of the plane.

Comment: @PseudoNeo   So if one endows the manifold with a (non-Euclidean) metric does that automatically imply that when one maps locally to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ one cannot use Cartesian coordinates as the geometry is not flat, even locally?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis    I put spherical polar coordinates as an example, but didn't phrase it very well (have updated it to try and make things a little clearer). What I meant was, couldn't one forgo the curvilinear coordinates altogether in this case and just use local Cartesian coordinates like $x^{1}=\sqrt{1-(x^{2})^{2}-(x^{3})^{2}}$ (with appropriate restrictions), why do curvilinear coordinates even need to be introduced?

Comment: @Will: I would call those "graph coordinates", and they are often quite ugly to work with - certainly they do not give you the Euclidean metric (unless the surface is locally just a plane). If you allow high enough codimension they do exist in general - any manifold can be isometrically embedded in a large enough $\mathbb R^n$, and we can just align our Cartesian axes with the tangent plane at a point of interest to get local graph coordinates.

Comment: @Will: you can always put some Coordinates (they're useful for computations), but you cannot ask them to preserve the metric (=to be *isometries*). If you have a chart which is an isometry, then your manifold is locally Euclidean, which is a very exceptional case. In Riemannian Geometry, it is sometimes important to use charts with extra properties (so that the problem you're studying has a nice expression), but these "extra properties" are always weaker than being an isometry because the manifold is not flat.

Comment: @PseudoNeo     I thought all manifolds were locally Euclidean though (in the sense that they "look like" $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ locally? Or is it that points on a manifold can locally be represented by $n$-tuples in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, however, the actually manifold may not be locally Euclidean (i.e. flat) and possess a varying metric with the coordinate patch that is being considered, thus we cannot use Cartesian coordinates to describe the manifold locally as these can only be used if it is flat?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis So, for example could we say that $S^{2}$ is, for a suitably small enough patch, locally just a plane and thus can be locally described by Euclidean coordinates (although more easily described in other coordinates)?

Answer (score 3):

A couple points:

1. the coordinate chart (or inversely a patch) does not *approximately* describe the manifold. It is *exactly* on the manifold. For example, at the top of the unit-sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ near the point $(0,0,1)$ it is true that $z=1$ locally approximates the sphere (it is the tangent plane), however, it is certainly not true that $\Phi(x,y) = (x,y,1)$ provides a patch of the sphere near $(0,0,1)$. We could use $\Psi ( x, y) = (x,y, \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} )$ as the image of $\Psi$ is on the sphere.
2. there are abstract examples of manifolds formed by sets of matrices, or projective spaces. Such examples have points which are not even in $\mathbb{R}^n$, thus, without some fine print, it is clearly impossible to use coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as coordinates for such manifolds. But...
3. item 2. is not quite as imposing as it appears because it is usually possible to find a model of the abstract manifold which fits inside some copy of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Moreover, Whitney's [Embedding Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem) and Nash's [Embedding Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_embedding_theorem) show that we can find a set $S$ inside $\mathbb{R}^k$ for $k$ sufficiently large to represent an abstract $n$-dimensional manifold $\mathcal{M}$ in such a way that $S$ has the same structure as $\mathcal{M}$. That structure could involve the metric, or just the topology, it depends on the type of manifold and theorem we wish to invoke. I point you to the links.
4. what is distance on a manifold ? This would seem to be part of your current confusion. For a given point-set, there are multiple structures we can place. For example, the plane can be given a metric which gives it spherical or hyperbolic geometry (angles add up to more or less than 180 degrees in a triangle). Of course, those metrics are not **induced** from the ambient Euclidean metric in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Likewise, for manifolds, the metric need not be induced from the metric on the larger space on which it is embedded. We develop a theory of geometry for Riemannian manifolds which is completely based on the abstract structure of the manifold itself. The *intrinsic* geometry of a manifold is independent of the details of its embedding. This is a bit of a mind-bender when you first come across the idea. In the classical differential geometry we have some mixture of intrinsic and extrinsic quantities for surfaces. For example, the mean curvature is extrinsic whereas the Gaussian curvature is intrinsic.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. In part 1. of your answer are $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ maps from (a subset of) $M$ to (a subset of) $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?  Part of what has confused me in reading some texts on diff. geom. is when they give an example of $S^{2}$ they define a coordinate chart such as $\phi :U\subset M\rightarrow V\subset\mathbb{R}^{n},\; \phi : (\theta, \phi)\mapsto (\sin (\theta)\cos (\phi),\sin (\theta)\sin (\phi),\cos (\theta)$. For me this confuses things as it makes it seem as if $(\theta, \phi)$ are points on the manifold, rather than coordinates $\mathbb{R}^{2}$?!

Comment: No my $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are "patches". The inverse maps are the coordinate "charts" on the sphere. Let me pick on an easier example, for the $z=1$ plane we have patch $\Phi(u,v) = (u,v,1)$. On the other hand, $\phi^{-1}(x,y,z) = (x,y)$ for all $(x,y,z)$ on the plane. Part of the confusion stems from the fact that we use $x,y,z$ as both fixed points and coordinate functions. I can write $\phi^{-1} = (x,y)$ this indicates $\phi^{-1}(a,b,c) = (x(a,b,c),y(a,b,c)) = (a,b)$. So, $(x,y)$ is a chart on the $z=1$ plane, but, understand, this views $x,y$ as real-valued functions with domain $z=1$.

Comment: To answer your question more abstractly, a patch is like the parametrizations we used in calculus III to set-up flux or surface integrals. A pair of parameters $(u,v)$  gives us a point $(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))$ on the surface. So, $(u,v)$ is not "on" the surface, but, they do set-up a coordinate system on the surface in a natural way. A chart takes its domain as some subset of the manifold and its image is in $\mathbb{R}^n$. When I talk about a system of coordinates on a manifold, I'm talking about a chart. On $\mathbb{R}^3$ we have three usual charts we use in calc. III.

Comment: JamesS.Cook    So is the statement "locally Euclidean" specifically saying that locally points on the manifold can be represent by $n$-tuples of real numbers in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and says nothing about whether the coordinate space is flat or that the coordinates are Cartesian?! Is the point that coordinates are just labels to keep track of where all the points on the manifold are, so within a given patch we are free to choose any coordinate system we like (although in practice we would choose one that suited the problem at hand), not just Cartesian or spherical polar etc.?

Comment: Also, for the example of the sphere, is it that we represent points in a given cooordinate patch by spherical polar coordinates (for example), such that a given point has a coordinate representation $(\theta, \phi)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$. As the manifold is locally flat within a sufficiently small neighbourhood of each point we can then map these coordinate representations to coordinates in the ambient 3-dimensional Euclidean space, whose coordinates are Cartesian, i.e. $(\theta, \phi)\mapsto (x, y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$?

Comment: Yep, curved manifolds (those with nontrivial curvature) are locally Euclidean. The term locally Euclidean is a topological condition. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_manifold for example. Yes, there are in principal many choices of coordinates, if we work with a maximal atlas then $\infty$-many coordinates are available.

Comment: Is there a good way to visualise coordinate lines on a manifold and why a particular set of coordinates would be better than another, e.g. why another set would be better to choose than Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: Well, I think this is my last comment here since the system gets grumpy now, but, to answer your last comment, I don't try to visualize past $n=2$. Generally, what is "good" depends on some symmetry of the example, for things built from sums of squares I see sines and cosines. For differences of squares I see cosh and sinh. Using cartesian coordinates is not usually good for explicit computations, unless, it's a plane or nice graph. There are no universal rules here. It is more of an art than an algorithm. See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/836833/36530